Spring DefaultMessageListener refreshConnectionUntilSuccesful logic can it be made optional
We have two app instances (PROD & COB) which use same clientID to connect to TIBCO topics. Whenever PROD instance is running it acquires a lock on one of the topics which is meant for exclusive lock for that particular instance, if successful then it will proceed with other topic connections.
Meanwhile, COB keeps on retrying the connection to the same lock topic with same clientID. We ran into an issue during TIBCO server failover. The TIBCO url comprises of both PROD and COB servers and during their failover testing, our PROD & COB instance both were unable to connect. The way the refresh connection logic works, PROD ended up giving away the connections to COB instance.
If you see SimpleMessageListener class there is an option to set recoverOnException flag. Is there a way we can have DefaultMessageListener class refresh connections only on certain exception/scenarios ?
The refresh logic causes the connection to be released and then acquired. This is an issue as any instance using same clientID can acquire the connection causing the original instance to keep on retrying when the connection stabilizes.
